# FASM - program doesn't work when using stack

Tags: stack, strlen, fasm

I'd like to know why my code isn't working when I'm trying to use stack.
Program have to print name of itself.

Here is code without using stack, which is working:

```
format elf executable
entry _start

segment readable executable
strlen:
    mov ebx,0
    strlen_loop:
        cmp byte [eax+ebx],0
        je strlen_end
        inc ebx
        jmp strlen_loop
    strlen_end:
        inc ebx
        ret
_start:
    mov eax,[esp+4]
    call strlen

    mov eax,4
    mov ecx,[esp+4]
    mov edx,ebx
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h

    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h
```

Here is code with using stack (program just exits/doing nothing):

```
format elf executable
entry _start

segment readable executable
strlen:
    mov ebx,0
    strlen_loop:
        cmp byte [eax+ebx],0
        je strlen_end
        inc ebx
        jmp strlen_loop
    strlen_end:
        inc ebx
        ret
_start:
    mov eax,[esp+4]
    call strlen
    push ebx

    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,0
    mov ecx,[esp+4]
    pop edx
    int 80h

    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm new in Linux development, but if I understood your problem, you have a mistake in this block:

```
mov eax,4
mov ebx,0
mov ecx,[esp+4] ; you wrote 'push' instruction above so value of 4 is incorrect now
pop edx
int 80h
```

You can just swap these two lines to fix this:

```
pop edx
mov ecx,[esp+4]
```